# How to get json response working properly in go

Tags: go

The code below works fine by displaying the json array data.
Here is the working Json response in the code below

```
 {"provision":"provision section 1",
    "subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "200 usd"}]}]}
```

Now I have New json response as follow. In the new json response below the parameter **subsets** is now 
surrounded by brackets **{}**

```
{
"provision":{"subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "200 usd"}]}]}
}
```

If I integrate the New json in the code it shows error **cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Head.Provision**. Any solutions on resolving the object issue will be appreciated

**Here is the code**

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Head struct {
    Provision  string `json:"provision"`
    Subsets []Subset `json:"subsets"`

}

type Subset struct {
    Payments []Payment `json:"payments"`
        Item string `json:"item"`
}

type Payment struct {
    Price string `json:"price"`
}

func main() {
/*
// old working json
    m := []byte(`

        {"provision":"provision section 1",
       "subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "200 usd"}]}]}

`)
*/

// New json response not working

m := []byte(`
    {
"provision":{"subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "200 usd"}]}]}
}  

`)

    r := bytes.NewReader(m)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r)

    val := &Head{}
    err := decoder.Decode(val)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

fmt.Println(val.Provision)


    // Subsets is a slice so you must loop over it 
    for _, s := range val.Subsets {
        fmt.Println(s.Item)
        // within Subsets, payment is also a slice
        // then you can access each price
        for _, a := range s.Payments {
            fmt.Println(a.Price)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You might want to bookmark this: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how I got it working. Thanks

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Head struct {
    Provision  Prov `json:"provision"`
    //Subsets []Subset `json:"subsets"`

}



type Prov struct {
   Subsets []Subset `json:"subsets"`
}





type Subset struct {
    Payments []Payment `json:"payments"`
        Item string `json:"item"`
}

type Payment struct {
    Price string `json:"price"`
}

func main() {

m := []byte(`

        {"provision":
       {"subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "200 usd"}]},
{"item":"SUGAR"},{"payments": [{"price": "600 usd"}]}
]}
}

`)


    r := bytes.NewReader(m)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r)

    val := &Head{}
    err := decoder.Decode(val)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

//fmt.Println(val.Provision)


    // Subsets is a slice so you must loop over it 
    for _, s := range val.Provision.Subsets {
        fmt.Println(s.Item)
        // within Subsets, payment is also a slice
        // then you can access each price
        for _, a := range s.Payments {
            fmt.Println(a.Price)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: While this code might work, it does not answer the question, because it offers no explanation as to why this code works while the original code does not. The code should also be formatted - as written it includes a ton of unnecessary whitespace which makes it much longer than necessary and therefore harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Head struct {
    Provision Provision `json:"provision"`
}

type Provision struct {
    Subsets []Subset `json:"subsets"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3TgxBOng1qE full version here.

Comment: Thank you Sir Nvcnvn for your contribution so far. I have ran the solution but gives too many other arrays and objects. It should just only show/print  value milk and 200 usd as response. Between Thanks

Comment: @NancyMooree what do you mean by too many other arrays? Or you mean by the printing format? https://play.golang.org/p/Ht6ERZz2s8L